# What are project management best practices using Microsoft Excel? Please include examples.

Tags: pm-software, tools

I saw this article from Mike Cohn on using Microsoft Excel to build a spreadsheet-based backlog:  http://blog.mountaingoatsoftware.com/a-sample-format-for-a-spreadsheet-based-product-backlog

It got me thinking: what are other PM best practices using Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 1):

One Page Project manager is one: https://www.oppmi.com/

I also think status is best done with a cut and paste from an excel as well.

Answer (score 1):

The NETWORKDAYS function in Excel is very powerful and can allow you to create spreadsheets showing tasks with start/end dates and durations.  You may need to get the Analysis Pack in older versions of Excel to use this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a software development budget plan excel sheet (it's an HTML but Excel can handle it):

http://projectcodemeter.com/cost_estimation/images/files/pcmreports/development_budget_plan.htm

Answer (score 1):

I found that CBT nugget series and Lynda Excel 2007/2010 video tutorials are very useful both for understanding excel and to get the best practices out of it. Probably, they teach you the simplest and most efficient way to get your work done.